# Python - using a method's return value as a constant

Tags: python, methods, constants

I am trying to define some constants at the top of my file. There are no classes in the file, just imports, constants, and methods. Possibly due to poor design, I want to use a method inside of this file to set a constant. For example:

```
MY_CONSTANT = function(foo, bar)

def function(foo, bar):
    return 6
```

In this example, I want MY_CONSTANT to get assigned the int 6. This is a simplified version of the problem, as my function actually makes many expensive calls and I only want that function to be called once. I plan to use the constant inside of a loop.

This does not work because I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

Is there a better design for this, or how can I use a method call to set my constant?

Comment: Sorry if you're assigning to it it's just a variable. There are no constants in Python per se, just the convention that you don't assign to variables in ALL CAPS, except when they are declared.

Comment: The problem, however, is that you're calling `function` before it's declared.

Comment: just move `MY_CONSTANT = function(foo, bar)` below the function.

Comment: Python reads files from top to bottom, therefore supporting other's comments that you are trying to declare a method before it has been identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a function before it has been defined:

```
def function(foo, bar):
    return 6

MY_CONSTANT = function(foo=None, bar=None)

>>>MY_CONSTANT
6
```

Edit: I set `foo=None` and `bar=None` going into `function` because I'm not sure where you have those defined either.

Comment: Ok, ok. I didn't want to do this because it looks ugly. But it is correct and nobody has given me a better idea. Thanks.